# Creating a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I am trying to create a vector from a list of file names in my current directory.

Say there are files, "a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "D.txt" in the directory, I want to create a vector V with ("a", "b", "c", "D").

```
myFiles <- c("a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "D.txt")
```

How could I achieve this in R?

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and revise your question

Comment: @Sotos revise it to what? Seems pretty self explanatory to me.

Comment: @mtoto I don't think it matters whether it's clear or not. Once a structure for questions is established from the community then I think all the questions shjould follow that structure regardless how simple they are. IMHO

Answer (score 3):

We could try

```
V <- gsub('\\..*', '', list.files())
```